# Prime as sum of square

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ an arbitrary prime number such that $p=r^2+s^2$, where $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Can I conclude that $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$?

I appreciate any hint. Thank you.

Comment: $$ 2 = \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^2 $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur: because the question is likely to be closed for lack of efforts, and I do not want to get credit for such trivial observation. On the other hand, helping the OP realizing that is not a bad thing in itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: There is another accent also: if prime $p$ can be written in the form $$p=r^2+s^2,$$ where $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$, then exists $r_0, s_0 \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$p=r_0^2+s_0^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't conclude that. For instance, $$5=\left(\frac{11}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^2$$